# Lambda@Edge and AWS EC2 latency comparison

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

Currently, I have built an application on EC2 instances in multiple regions. The problems are when one instance per region need to patch/maintain, and we need more effort to handle if something fails.

I decide to use Lambda@Edge instead of EC2 and question is:

1. Lambda@Edge is better than these EC2 instances?
2. Need to make sure that Lambda@Edge would be reachable with the same latency or better than EC2. Have any official docs to prove this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue you're facing is one of patching and maintenance of instances then yes, Lambda or Lambda@Edge will absolutely remove that issue.

If the issue is latency and you want to keep your instances you could create an [Amazon Cloudfront Distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) that would go in front of your instances and serve cached content to your users - that might be the easiest way to start out.

Lambda@Edge would have the same latency as Cloudfront. Lambda functions that are deployed to CloudFront edge locations have a [couple of limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-lambda-at-edge).

Comment: Thanks. But have any related docs to describes it? Ex:

1. <30ms request processing time
2. <10 ms latency from worldwide users

Comment: @ManhNguyen you can't really guarantee latency since the client plays a part in that. I don't think any CDN can guarantee latency like that. I really doubt you'll get <10ms latency worldwide. You can see the page here as an example of CDN endpoint latency: http://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html

In terms of request processing time yes <30ms to pass it off to your lambda function but the time after that depends on how long your function takes. Serving directly from the cache instead of invoking a lambda will certainly complete in <30ms.

Comment: you can see a quick test here: https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-aws:cloudfront